# Leer un archivo txt y pasarlo a una lista

Tags: java

txt que quiero meter en una lista:

> 0.1,0.08,0.04,0.01,0.04
>
> 0.2,0.15,0.02,0,0.06

significado txt:

> cantidadNutrientes1,cantidadNutrientes2,cantidadNutrientes3,cantidadNutrientes4,coste

siendo cada linea un ingrediente

```
public void leeArchivo(String file) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    String cadena;
    FileReader f = new FileReader(file);
    BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(f);

    while((cadena = b.readLine())!=null) {
        String[] parts = cadena.split(",");
        Ingrediente ing = new Ingrediente();
        ing.setCantidadNutrientes(Double.parseDouble(parts[0]));
        ing.setCoste(Double.parseDouble(parts[1]));
    }

    b.close();
}
```

La idea es meter el txt en una `List<Ingrediente>`, para poder trabajar en esa lista. Aunque ahora que lo pienso, como tengo varios ingredientes, seria mas bien un `List<List<Ingrediente>>` o eso creo.

Tengo una clase `Ingrediente` como:

```
public class Ingrediente {

    private Integer codigo;
    private Double cantidadNutrientes;
    private Double coste;

    public Ingrediente(Double cantidadNutrientes, Double coste) {
        super();
        this.codigo = null;
        this.cantidadNutrientes = cantidadNutrientes;
        this.coste = coste;
    }

    public Ingrediente(){
        this.cantidadNutrientes = new Double(cantidadNutrientes);
        this.coste = new Double(coste);
    }

    public Ingrediente(String s) {
        String[] v = s.split("[ ,]");
        Integer ne = v.length;
        if (ne != 1)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Formato no adecuado en línea  " + s);
        cantidadNutrientes = new Double(v[0]);
        coste = new Double(v[1]);
    }

    public Ingrediente(Integer codigo, String[] s) {
        super();
        this.codigo = codigo;
        this.cantidadNutrientes = new Double(s[0]);
        this.coste = new Double(s[1]);

    }

    public static Ingrediente create(String s) {
        return new Ingrediente(s);
    }

    public static Ingrediente create(Integer codigo, String[] s) {
        return new Ingrediente(codigo, s);
    }

    public Integer getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public void setCodigo(Integer codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public Double getCantidadNutrientes() {
        return cantidadNutrientes;
    }

    public void setCantidadNutrientes(Double cantidadNutrientes) {
        this.cantidadNutrientes = cantidadNutrientes;
    }

    public Double getCoste() {
        return coste;
    }

    public void setCoste(Double coste) {
        this.coste = coste;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((cantidadNutrientes == null) ? 0 : cantidadNutrientes.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((codigo == null) ? 0 : codigo.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((coste == null) ? 0 : coste.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Ingrediente other = (Ingrediente) obj;
        if (cantidadNutrientes == null) {
            if (other.cantidadNutrientes != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!cantidadNutrientes.equals(other.cantidadNutrientes))
            return false;
        if (codigo == null) {
            if (other.codigo != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!codigo.equals(other.codigo))
            return false;
        if (coste == null) {
            if (other.coste != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!coste.equals(other.coste))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "" + cantidadNutrientes + coste + "";
    }

}
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75637/discussion-on-question-by-fblanco89-leer-un-archivo-txt-y-pasarlo-a-una-lista-j).

Comment: son 4 cantidades de nutrientes por ingrediente segun el archivo, pero solo 1 atributo `cantidadNutrientes` en la clase `Ingrediente`?

Comment: A ver, en el ejercicio en cuestion, tengo una tabla de nutrientes y otra de ingredientes. Por una lado me dan 4 nutrientes de los que se el codigo(que seria el indice) y la cantidadMinima por cada nutriente. Por otro lado, tengo 2 ingredientes, los cuales estan compuestos por los 4 nutrientes y un coste. Entonces la idea es crear una listaNutrientes y otra listaIngredientes. Tengo dos ficheros, uno con lo datos de nutrientes y otro con los de ingrediente.Lo que quiero es pasar los txt a cada lista para luego poder resolver el ejercicio. Espero haberme explicado correctamente

Comment: @Klaimmore viendo lo que me acabas de decir, he encontrado un fallo, en la clase ingrediente, cantidadNutrientes no es un Double, es una lista<Integer> donde cada posicion es un nutriente

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tu problema esta aqui:

```
 while((cadena = b.readLine())!=null) {
            System.out.println(cadena);
    }

    b.close();
    return cadena;
```

El while loop corre hasta que cadena = null, y luego retornas cadena.  Tu funcion siempre retornaria null;

Comment: Más bien, esa es la idea de validar el `null`, cuando el lector termine de leer el archivo, retornará `null` y finalmente, terminará el bucle.

Comment: En caso de que **siempre** sea `null` no pasaría por el bucle

Comment: Me refiero cuando termina el bucle, para poder salir de el, la variable tiene que ser null.

Comment: No, el loop no tiene problemas. Mira la documentación [readLine()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine())

Comment: Es correcta la apreciación de @alanfcm. No dice que el problema sea el bucle, sino que, como la condición de este indica que la ejecución termina cuando la variable `cadena` sea `null`, y esta siempre se hará `null` cuando ya no hayan datos que leer del archivo, pues entonces el método siempre retornará `null`. Pero del mismo modo, no creo que el problema radique en que el método retorne siempre `null`, ya que el objetivo de este es llenar la lista con los datos del archivo. Lo que no entiendo es para que debe retornar algo.

Comment: Así es, @E. Betanzos, la apreciación es correcta, sin embargo, no es válida en este caso, porque @alanfcm propone que la función siempre retorna `null`, sin embargo no es así (reitero, en este caso). Por lo tanto, no funciona como una respuesta válida para la pregunta.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo en que no es una respuesta válida, pero con ese código el método siempre retorna `null`, porque la variable `cadena` será `null` cuando se termine de leer el archivo, y esto siempre ocurre.

Comment: @E.Betanzos, ah, ya entiendo a lo que te refieres, tienes razón,